# Joining two tables using a range substring

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, substring, join

I have two tables that I need to join. I am attempting to match the first two digits of a number on a table (A) with a range of numbers that are listed on another table (B). The Result will be the entire record of Table A with the Careholders of Table B.

These are the tables:

Table A:

```
CREATE TABLE [db].[Annual_Capture](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Main_TIN] [char](9),
[MainTaxpayerName] [varchar](20),
[Main_AbstractNumber] [char](3),
[Year] [int] NULL
```

Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE [db].[CAREHOLDERS_TIN](
[Care_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Care_EINStart] [char](2),
[Care_EINEnd] [char](2),
[Care_Owner] [varchar](20)
```

I am not a SQL Guru, so I do not know the proper syntax despite searching endlessly.
I am attempting to use the following with no luck:

```
Select A.*, B.Care_Owner

FROM db.Annual_Capture as A,
inner join db.CAREHOLDERS_TIN as B
On A.Main_TIN = 
SUBSTRING(A.Main_TIN, 1, 2)>= B.Care_EINStart 
AND SUBSTRING(A.Main_TIN, 1, 2) <= B.Care_EINEnd
```

Note: Main_TIN is a char (9) and Care_EINStart/Care_EINEnd are char(2). So if Main_TIN is 867530900. I am looking for the CareOwner that is assigned EINStart/Care_EINEnd that is like 80/90. I have to do this for all A.Main_TIN's and join them with there assigned B.Care_Owners. This will proably end up in a stored procedure or more likely a view.

Much Appreciated if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.  I just provided the proper syntax:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Care_Owner
FROM db.Annual_Capture AS A
    INNER JOIN db.CAREHOLDERS_TIN AS B
        ON SUBSTRING(A.Main_TIN, 1, 2) >= B.Care_EINStart 
            AND SUBSTRING(A.Main_TIN, 1, 2) <= B.Care_EINEnd
```